How can I disable the file delete confirmation dialog in IntelliJ IDEA?
enter image description here
Hi everyone,
I’m looking to streamline my workflow in IntelliJ IDEA by disabling the confirmation dialog that appears when I delete files. I prefer to delete files directly without being prompted for confirmation each time.
Could someone guide me on how to turn off this confirmation dialog in IntelliJ IDEA? I have checked the settings but couldn’t find the relevant option.
I’m using IntelliJ IDEA version 2024.1.
Thanks in advance for your help!
What I tried:
Checked the Settings:
I navigated to File > Settings (Preferences on macOS) > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings.
I looked for options related to file deletion confirmation but couldn’t find any specific setting to disable the confirmation dialog.
Searched the Documentation:
I reviewed the IntelliJ IDEA documentation and online resources but didn’t find a clear answer on how to disable the confirmation dialog for file deletions.
What I expected:
I expected to find an option or checkbox in the settings that would allow me to disable the confirmation dialog when deleting files.
What actually resulted:
Despite my efforts, I was unable to locate the relevant setting to disable the confirmation dialog. The dialog still appears when I attempt to delete files.

This option is not supported

or, alternatively, suppress the confirmation dialog if a modifier key is pressed.
I'd love to have same support for copy/move operations as well.
